# R: combinatorics, number of permutations for one combination

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I have three different events (1,2,3) with different probabilities (0.15, 0.76, 0.09) and I would like to draw 5 times with replacement.
I can now determine the number of possible combinations using

```
nsimplex(3,5)  ### =21
```

from the combinat-package.
And I can determine the probabilities of each combination using

```
mySimplex <- xsimplex(3,5)
myProbs<-c(0.15, 0.76, 0.09)
results<- apply(mySimplex,2,dmultinom,prob=myProbs)
```

Further, I can of course determine the number of permutations by calculating 3^5= 243.

But how do I know how often each permutation of the same combination is drawn without counting them manually? That is, how many permutations are in each of my combinations?

If I undestand that correctly, there are 243 permutations building 21 different combinations. Now my question is, how many permutations build each combination. E.g. the combination {1,1,1,1,1} will be built up only once, whereas others are created by several permutations.

I guess you can come to this by using the probabilities for each combination but I do not know how to do it? Or is there any other way to easiliy determine that in R?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: if each permutation of a given combination is equally likely, you would expect total draws * P(combination) / #permutations for a given permutation of a combination

Comment: Is a draw of {1,1,1,2,2} in the same group as one resulting in {2,1,2,1,1}? In other words: are you actually considering different permutations as distinct? You should also post R-code the presents the problem and your efforts at building a solution.

Comment: yes, {1,1,1,2,2} and {2,1,2,1,1}  would build the same combination. And I wish to know how many of these permutations build the same combination (e.g. three times 1, two times 2). I'll edit my post to clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of permutations of `a` indistinguishable copies of item 1, `b` of item 2, `c` of item 3, where `a + b + c = N`, is `N! / (a! b! c!)`.

For example if you had `(a,b,c) = (3,1,1)` then there are `5!/(3! 1! 1!) = 20` arrangements.

```
  c  b  a  a  a    b  a  c  a  a    a  b  a  a  c    a  a  c  a  b    
  c  a  b  a  a    b  a  a  c  a    a  c  b  a  a    a  a  b  c  a    
  c  a  a  b  a    b  a  a  a  c    a  c  a  b  a    a  a  b  a  c    
  c  a  a  a  b    a  b  c  a  a    a  c  a  a  b    a  a  a  b  c    
  b  c  a  a  a    a  b  a  c  a    a  a  c  b  a    a  a  a  c  b
```

In general, we can calculate the number as follows

```
nperm<-function(...) {
   args<-as.numeric(list(...));
   num<-lfactorial(sum(args));
   den<-sum(lfactorial(args));
   return(round(exp(num-den)));
}
```

So, e.g.,

```
x<-expand.grid(0:5,0:5,0:5)
x<-x[rowSums(x)==5,]
x[,"nperm"]<-apply(x,1,function(x) do.call(nperm,as.list(x)))

Var1 Var2 Var3 nperm
   5    0    0     1
   4    1    0     5
   3    2    0    10
   2    3    0    10
   1    4    0     5
   0    5    0     1
   4    0    1     5
   3    1    1    20
   2    2    1    30
   1    3    1    20
   0    4    1     5
   3    0    2    10
   2    1    2    30
   1    2    2    30
   0    3    2    10
   2    0    3    10
   1    1    3    20
   0    2    3    10
   1    0    4     5
   0    1    4     5
   0    0    5     1
```

And `sum(x[,"nperm"]) == 243`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To make this reproducible, I would have needed to use `set.seed(<some_value>)` but this is one attempt at using `sample` to draw distinct combinations (without considering the permutations distinct. If the permutations are to be considered distinct, then take out the `sort` step:

```
table(                    # get the counts of distinct combinations
   apply(                 # this will collapse values by column
      replicate(100000,   # yields a 100,000 column matrix
             {sample(c("1","2","3"), 5 ,repl=TRUE, prob=c(.5,.25,.25) )}), 
           2, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=".")) )

1.1.1.1.1 1.1.1.1.2 1.1.1.1.3 1.1.1.2.2 1.1.1.2.3 1.1.1.3.3 1.1.2.2.2 
     3090      7705      8144      7851     15408      7649      3997 
1.1.2.2.3 1.1.2.3.3 1.1.3.3.3 1.2.2.2.2 1.2.2.2.3 1.2.2.3.3 1.2.3.3.3 
    11731     11554      3940       949      3844      5955      4019 
1.3.3.3.3 2.2.2.2.2 2.2.2.2.3 2.2.2.3.3 2.2.3.3.3 2.3.3.3.3 3.3.3.3.3 
      961        99       506       990       997       510       101
```

A.Webb suggests we compare theory `dmultinom` to practice:

```
dmultinom(c(4,1,0),prob=c(0.5,0.25,0.25))*2
[1] 0.15625
```

So prediction for first value 3125 looks arguably accurate vs simulated at 3090 and for the second and third value as well at 7812.5 vs 7705 and 8144.

Comment: These probabilities may be calculated with `dmultinom(c(5,0,0),prob=c(0.5,0.25,0.25))` for all 5 the first, `dmultinom(c(4,1,0),prob=c(0.5,0.25,0.25))` for 4 of the first and 1 of the second, etc...

Comment: Thanks. Clarifies the theory but it's still not clear what the OP wants. He might actually want permutations.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that I do not want to predict these numbers by lots of replicates. As there are 243 permutations building 21 combinations, I would like to know how These 243 split into the 21 combinations. When I insert 243 in your proposed code, I will no get my 21 combinations.

Comment: I don't know how one would insert 243 into my code. I did suggest that if it were permutations you were actually interest in seeing, then you could just remove the `sort()` call. That does return a table of length 243. If you only wanted their names then just retun `names` applied to the table.